# I am getting this error in Fast API FileResponse "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte"

Tags: python, fastapi, fileresponse

I am trying to send a file in response to an API. I have file in my "data" folder on server and I am trying to sent that file. I've checked path of file and it is fine. I am getting this error on file send:

> "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte".

Here is my code snippet:

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse, FileResponse

app = create_app()

@app.get("/static/{filename}")
def serve_image(filename: str)-> None:
    file_path = Path("data") / filename
    if not file_path.is_file():
        raise NotFoundException("File not fount")
    return FileResponse(file_path)
```

Complete Error:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 292, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 83, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/authentication.py", line 48, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Volumes/Data/Study/NTNU/IMT4886 Applied Computer Science Project/Code/medical-image-analytics-backend/core/fastapi/middlewares/response_logger.py", line 37, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _logging_send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 69, in app
    await response(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/responses.py", line 358, in __call__
    await send(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 65, in sender
    await send(message)
  File "/Volumes/Data/backend/core/fastapi/middlewares/response_logger.py", line 33, in _logging_send
    response_info.body += body.decode("utf8")
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: If you read the error message, you'll see that it's your middleware in `response_logger.py` that's generating the error. If you want help  I'd suggest posting that too.

Comment: error may suggest that you expect data in UTF-8 but you get data in different encoding - probably `LATIN-1`, `CP1250`. etc. How do you send file to API? Did you use `UTF-8` in response?

Comment: @furas - I might be mistaken. Perhaps you mean cp1252?

Comment: @S3DEV frankly, I was guessing :) There are many code pages `cp125x`. All depends on from what country is OP :) And it may need to check `0x89` to detect which code pages it needs. And the same is with `Latin-X` encodings

Comment: It's probably a binary file (since you're serving it from /static), and the middleware is trying to parse it as a string. That assumption won't always be correct, so you end up with attempting to parse random binary data as UTF-8 (it shouldn't need any codepage, it should be kept as a bytes type).